# Java Adapter Annotations

Tags: java, junit, annotations

In an effort to design components that are as reusable as possible, I got to thinking recently about the possibility of so-called "adapter annotations."  By this, I mean the application of the classic `Adapter` OO pattern to Java annotations. So for example, let's say I have a unit testing suite that is entirely JUnit-based. I would need to annotate all of my test methods as follows:

```
public class WidgetTest
{
    @Test
    public void test_WidgetConstructor()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But what if, after creating a test suite with, say, 1000 test classes, I decide I want to begin unit testing with some brand new super-cool testing framework that requires all test methods to be annotated as follows:

```
public class WidgetTest
{
    @SuperCoolUnitTest(someParam="true")
    public void test_WidgetConstructor()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, in this particular example it *might* be perfectly feasible to search-n-replace the old annotations for the new ones, but in a practicle application, this would not be a feasible solution.

So would it be possible for me "wrap" my unit test annotations with something homegrown, like:

```
public class WidgetTest
{
    @HomegrownUnitTestAnnotation
    public void test_WidgetConstructor()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then build my own annotation processor that would convert instances of `@HomegrownUnitTestAnnotation` to whichever annotation I currently need (either `@Test` or `@SuperCoolUnitTest(someParam="true")`)?

Obviously, this question applies to all annotations, not just those provided by JUnit.  I'm basically asking if it is possible to wrap 3rd party annotations for the sake of reusability/separation of concerns/etc. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the 'brand new test framework' is required to dump the JUnit API (like Assert...) as well?

Comment: There are many cases where only annotations are used to decorate classes and methods, without any API calls being invoked inside those methods. Like I stated in the question, this is not a JUnit-specific scenario, I'm asking if it is possible to even build annotation processors that can map one type of annotation to another.

Comment: Ahhhhh very nice! Thanks @home. I guess the short answer to my question is "yes", although I'm wondering if there is a "pure Java" (non-Spring) way to do this. Obviously though, if Spring does it with these meta-annotations, then it must be possible to make a homegrown solution.  If you change your comment to an answer I'll happily check it for you. Thanks again.

Comment: This is what I thought - maybe you can just have a look at how it works in Spring and apply the same concept for your solution. Created an answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Spring's meta-annotations. It seems to me that this is the concept you're looking for: http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/06/spring-framework-30-m3-released/.

You may be able to apply the same concept to your own application.